# Ensure that a macro defined with \newcommand is always rendered in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, macros, environments

I'd like to define a command `\Lm`, such that if used in a maths environment it is replaced with `\mathcal{L}`, but when used outside of the maths environment it would be replaced with `$\mathcal{L}$`. This would allow me to write both a sentence like this:

```
$\langle \Lm, \R \rangle$ is a \emph{deductive system}
consisting of a language \Lm and a set of inference rules \R;
```

I know how to write either of those behaviours separately: `\newcommand{\Lm}{$\mathcal{L}$}`, `\newcommand{\Lm}{\mathcal{L}}`, but I'm not sure if there is a way to decide which one to use based on the environment I'm in.

Comment: I'd recommend writing `consisting of a language $\Lm$ and ...`. The symbol is math, after all; you gain little in not properly segregating math as math.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this specific problem, you can define your command as

```
\newcommand{\Lm}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}}
```